# 'A non well formed numeric value encountered' on text string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a bit of code the refuses to run, giving the error;

```
[ErrorException]                             
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

I've read an awful lot about it, but all of the solutions seem to have dealt with people not using `number_format`, `date` or `strtotime` correctly.

My code can be as simple as the below whilst giving the error;

```
$plan == 'Event';
if($plan !== 'Event') {
    $cost_of_report = $cost_of_report * 2;
}
```

The line `$cost_of_report = $cost_of_report * 2;` works on its own.

I've echoed out `gettype($plan)`and it is a string.

I'm using this in a Laravel artisan command with in Laravel 4.2 on PHP 5.6.31.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong or what I can do to try and get this working?

Comment: For the record: `$plan == 'Event';` does not assign a values to `$plan`.  If it did, the if condition wouldn't result in `true` thus never running `$cost_of_report = $cost_of_report * 2;`.  Perhaps edit your "simple as" snippet.  Does this exception come because the `if` is never satisfied and `$cost_of_report` is never recast as a number due to arithmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem here is not with `$plan` but with `$cost_of_report`. Make sure it's number

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I echoed out the gettype of that variable and it was a string, so I put a line in that reads `$cost_of_report = floatval($cost_of_report);` and now it works. I'll mark your answer as correct, but can you explain why `$cost_of_report = $cost_of_report * 2;` works outside the if statement?

Comment: It should work without any difference in `if` or outside of it. So maybe you had different value or this is PHP bug or this is your server/environment related - see https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/928

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't converted $cost_of_report to number_format() before the calculation.

Try doing the calculations before converting to number_format()

Hope this helps.

Comment: And also avoid $cost_of_report = "100"; as this will assume that 100 is a string and not an integer.